# WYGWAM "Read More" button has been replaced with "Remove Formatting" somehow

Tags: wygwam, pixelandtonic

Not sure how this happened, but I was clicking the hell out the "read More" button to insert an excerpt break and nothing was happening. When I left the mouse pointer over the button to see what the tooltip said the text read "Remove Formatting" even though the icon is correct.

In addition, the "Remove Format" button is now missing entirely.

Any idea why this might be happening?

[image]

EE Version 2.6.1

WYGWAM Version 3.0.2

Full configuration screen (they're all displaying the same issue):

[image]

Comment: EE version, Wygwam version, any recent updates to EE or to Wygwam or to any server software...? Has anything changed on the server side?

Comment: Sorry… updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough this problem just disappeared after a day or so and hasn't come back. No idea what the source issue was.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating to [WYGWAM 3.1.2](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam) as it is EE 2.6+ compatible.

Comment: Updated and still seeing the issue. Attached a new screenshot above of one of the WYWAM configuration screens. They're all displaying the same issue.